# Как работает данный лексер ? Не очень понимаю принцип работы

Tags: java, лексер

Класс main

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Lexems lex = new Lexems();
        LinkedList<Token> tokens = new LinkedList<Token>();

        String test = "q = 300 - 150 * 2 + 3 / 5";

        String str_1 = "";


        for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {

            if (test.toCharArray()[i] == ' ') {
                continue;
            }

            str_1 += test.toCharArray()[i];
            String str_2 = " ";
            if(i < test.length()-1){
                str_2 = str_1 + test.toCharArray()[i+1];
            }

            for (String key: lex.lexems.keySet()) {

                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(lex.lexems.get(key));

                Matcher m_1 = p.matcher(str_1);
                Matcher m_2 = p.matcher(str_2);


                if (m_1.find() && !m_2.find()) {
                    tokens.add(new Token(key.toString(), str_1));
                    str_1 = "";
                }
            }
        }

        for (Token t: tokens) {
            System.out.println(t.type + " " + t.token);
        }

    }
```

Класс Lexems

```
public class Lexems {

    static Map<String, String> lexems = new HashMap<String,String>();

    public Lexems(){
        lexems.put("VAR", "^[a-z]+$");
        lexems.put("DIGIT", "^0|[1-9][0-9]*$");
        lexems.put("OPERATOR", "^[-|+|/|*]$");
        lexems.put("ASSIGNMENT OPERATOR", "^=$");
    }

}
```

Класс Token

```
public class Token {

    String type;
    String token;

    Token(String Type, String Token){
        type = Type;
        token = Token;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё на самом деле очень просто.

Целью лексера является разбить текст на *лексемы* (их часто называют также *токенами*): например, «число», «идентификатор», «арифметический оператор». Разбиение происходит последовательно, по кусочкам. Чтобы определить, какой из лексем является следующий кусок текста, автор кода использует регулярные выражения, которые задают вид каждой лексемы.

Таким образом, код ведёт себя так: он ищет, какой из лексем соответствует начало текста, запоминает эту лексему, откусывает от текста прочитанную лексему, и повторяет процесс до исчерпания текста.

---

Я описал идеальный вариант, но данный код делает немного странно. Он накапливает текущую часть строки в переменной, и делает проверку: если текущая строка принимается регуляркой, а вот строка со следующим символом уже нет, то токен считается оконченным. Это не самая хорошая идея: лучше было бы переписать регулярки так, чтобы они не обращали внимания на «хвост» текста, и выбирали наибольший подходящий кусок.

Кроме того, метод компилирует регулярки на каждом входящем символе. Это затратно, намного проще было бы скомпилировать их один раз перед циклом.

Comment: Большое спасибо!)

Comment: @Maxim: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста дураку еще одну вещь, я не могу никак понять, зачем нам нужны str_1 и str_2. Почему именно две строки?

Comment: @Maxim: Ну, не то чтобы они были реально _нужны_. Автор кода использует их так: в первой строке у нас текущий кусок, а во второй то же самое плюс один следующий символ. Например, если мы разбираем строку `"12+34"`, у нас снчала `str_1 = "1"` и `str_2 = "12"`, обе подходят под числовой паттерн. На следующей итерации `str_1 = "12"` и `str_2 = "12+"`, и `str_2` уже не подходит под числовой паттерн.